# Why is my Google Colab instance crashing with this usage of numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I need to train a neural network for my final year project, Non-Intensive Load Monitoring.

Here I load a data set of 7000x3600 and reshape is as 7000x3600x200.

In this reshaping process, my instance crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Used Libraries- Numpy, Tensofflow & Pandas

```
training_set=(training_set*100).applymap(np.int16)+99
training_set_py=training_set.to_numpy()
training_set_formatted = []

for i in range(0,7000):
  temp_set = np.zeros([200,3600])
  for j in range(0, 3600):
    temp_set[training_set_py[i][j]][j] = 1
  training_set_formatted.append(temp_set)
```

Comment: That's about 40 gigabytes of array you're trying to allocate there.

Comment: Even when here people can tell you have a memory issue, for the future it would be good to provide the error messages you get or in what way your instance crashes, what do you mean by that.